# How to prevent Numbers from changing currency automatically

Tags: numbers, formatting

I have a spreadsheet that has cells with two currencies: USD and EUR.

I have a cell that is a USD formatted cell and the other, a EUR cell.

The EUR cell values are results of the multiplication of the USD formatted cell values with a given figure as exchange rate.

Now, Numbers does not let me manually change the EUR cell to EUR; when I click "Cell" -> Data Format -> "Currency" and chose a EUR, it reverts back to USD.

I would like to have control over the currency to assign a specific cell as I used to prior to version 4.3 (5046) of Numbers.

Because most of my formulas are now broken as I can no longer make use of more than one currency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue in Numbers version 4.3. Setting the value of the exchange rate cell to target currency seemed to fix the issue. So, in my case I was converting USD to JPY. If the exchange rate cell was formatted as "number," Numbers would revert the cell with the multiplication result to a USD format. But if I set the exchange rate cell format to "Currency" and JPY, I am then able to also set the format of the cell with the multiplication result to JPY.

Comment: This is a great work-around. It works as follows: a) Create a new cell (e.g. in B3), fill it with '1', assign a very exotic currency to this field. b) Add that "*B3" to any formula you would like to change the currency on (no matching of currencies required). This multiplies times 1, so not changing the cell content but since it is a new currency in the mix the resulting cell can be assigned any currency you would like. Is this nice/elegant? No! Does it work? YES! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem which may be related. In my case Numbers 4.3 allows me to specify the ratio of two currency cells as a number or a percentage but then immediately and automatically reverts the cell back to the currency format of one of the origin cells. I agree that Apple Developers are probably trying to 'help' (but don't realise that they don't yet have the competence to do so infallibly).

I have reported the problem via Apple's Feedback on:
 https://www.apple.com/feedback/numbers.html 
and suggest you do likewise. The more of us that report it the more likely they'll sort it. 
Meantime I have had to remove the currency format from my origin cells and added it to the description in the row/column headers. (Not ideal, I know.)